# Accelerate framework on iphone

Tags: iphone, accelerate-framework

Accelerate framework is nice if I want to do some algebra on vectors or calculate ffts. 
But, unless I'm missing something, in case I want to calculate cosine (or any other trig) of values in a vector there is no way to do that with accelerate. Also, vecLib is marked as unavailable on iphone and vDSP is missing things like square roots, logarithms, trigonometric functions...

Am I really correct? o_O

If I am, how to speed up the calculations of these missing functions and take advantage of facilities accelerate is using?

---

### The answer:

As MrMage said below, there is a `vv...` family of functions available in Accelerate. These include trigs, log's, roots, etc. But no complex numbers support. Thanks MrMage!

Comment: I would still like someone to lend me a hand here but in the meantime I will give [eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) a try and report back.

Comment: It seems that with gcc 4.2 which is used by newest XCode the speedup part of Eigen's advantage (vectorization) is unavailable... Of course, blame it on the Apple. Newest gcc is 4.7.0. Gcc 4.2 is a guest from the past - released May 13, 2007... Will have to look for a way to change the compiler.

Comment: latest Xcode doesn't use gcc at all, it provides the llvm compiler.

Comment: Well, that's true. After reading some material in the net about compilation problems with vectorization enabled and gcc4.2 I sincerely thought the compiler is the problem. It seems it was a problem some time ago. It compiles nicely with llvm, xcode 4.3, ios 5. On the mac vectorization is enabled and running. Can't check the phone, though, because just upgraded it to ios 5.1 forgetting about how to get xcode upgraded as well while in the hospital... Will get discharged soon fortunately :D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the iOS 5.1 docs, at least `vvsinf` (and similar functions from vecLib) are available in iOS 5.0 and later. I guess this should fulfill your needs.

Comment: That's true, don't know how could I miss that one... Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My reading of the documentation tells me that Accelerate/vfp.h exists on iOS, and that the trig functions are in there. However I haven't tried using it, so I'll carry on on the assumption that I'm wrong.

Fast trig implementations turn out not to be very clever. There's a maths thing called the Taylor expansion, which says, roughly:

```
sin(theta+epsilon) = sin(theta) + x*epsilon + small corrections
```

So that means you can build a lookup table that, for key values of theta, records sin(theta) and x. You then do the equation above, which is really fast (look at Accelerate's Fused Add and Multiply).

Comment: As for the vfp.h, unfortunately for example: `extern vFloat  vsinf(vFloat arg) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_0, __IPHONE_NA);`. Notice the **__IPHONE_NA** part. As for workaround you proposed, Taylor expansion is exactly what I wanted to escape cheaply :). Nevertheless, it's a viable solution taking advantage of vDSP.